# OAUTH : making the request failed (Couldn't connect to server)

Tags: php, magento, oauth

I installed the OAUTH Module which the server running on CentOS 6 + Php 5.3 Version.

And my application is developed under magento (php).

When calling the OAUTH URL from the browser it returns,

http://xxx.xxx.com:90/rematch/test.php

making the request failed (Couldn't connect to server)

Comment: If Oauth is installed correctly on server then it may be configuration issue from Magento side. Try this   http://www.aschroder.com/2012/04/introduction-to-the-magento-rest-apis-with-oauth-in-version-1-7/